# Adding a user specified date to existing code

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, user-input

I'm a but stuck with being able to add a user defined date to this Days to Go code. Works well with a set date embedded. But can't get this to work with the input lines.

```py
from datetime import datetime, time

b = input
event = (input('What is the name of your event?'))  # input the name of the event
year = int(input('Enter a year'))  # input the requires year
month = int(input('Enter a month'))  # input the required month
day = int(input('Enter a day'))  # input the required day

def date_diff_in_seconds(dt2, dt1):
    timedelta = dt2 - dt1
    return timedelta.days * 24 * 3600 + timedelta.seconds


def dhms_from_seconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return (days, hours, minutes, seconds)


# Specified date
date1 = datetime.date(b[1], b[2], b[3])

# Current date
date2 = datetime.now()

print("\n%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds" %
      dhms_from_seconds(date_diff_in_seconds(date2, date1)))
print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you wrongly used `b=input`. It means you want to use `input` function with function name b, such as `event = b('what is the name of your event?')`.

Instead, you can assign values to `b` like `b = (event, year, month, day)` after getting information using `input()`.

And you imported `datetime` module by `from datetime import datetime` you don't need to explitly say `datetime.date`, just `date`. However, you can use `datetime` rather than `date` here, as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime, time

#b = input -> wrong usage
event = (input('What is the name of your event? '))  # input the name of the event
year = int(input('Enter a year '))  # input the requires year
month = int(input('Enter a month '))  # input the required month
day = int(input('Enter a day '))  # input the required day
b = (event, year, month, day) # you can assign date values to b

def date_diff_in_seconds(dt2, dt1):
    timedelta = dt2 - dt1
    return timedelta.days * 24 * 3600 + timedelta.seconds


def dhms_from_seconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return (days, hours, minutes, seconds)


# Specified date
date1 = datetime(b[1], b[2], b[3]) # not datetime.date()

# Current date
date2 = datetime.now()

print("\n%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds" %
      dhms_from_seconds(date_diff_in_seconds(date2, date1)))
print()

# if you want to print the event together:
print("\n%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds left for %s" % (
            dhms_from_seconds(date_diff_in_seconds(date2, date1)) + (event,)))
```

The result is like:

```
What is the name of your event? birthday
Enter a year 2022
Enter a month 03
Enter a day 19

0 days, 14 hours, 40 minutes, 2 seconds
0 days, 14 hours, 40 minutes, 2 seconds left for Sunday # in case that you print the event together
```

Comment: This is a great explanation! Thank you, makes much more sense now.

Comment: @Drew So happy to hear that :) Plz upvote, accept my answer if you satisfied with my answer. It will also help other people who are suffering from this kind of issues.

Comment: Done! (I think, sorry new to this)

Comment: I'm getting a negative day count when I put in tomorrows date... Is this a time zone problem?

Comment: What is the name of your event? Tomorrow
Enter a year 2022
Enter a month 03
Enter a day 20

-1 days, 18 hours, 44 minutes, 22 seconds

Comment: @Drew Oh, the it is because of timezone, so it will show different result on your computer.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, just seems weird it's a negative countdown. What is the best way to print the Event name the user has typed before the date difference? e.g. "Birthday is 0 days, 14 hours, 40 minutes, 2 seconds away"

Comment: I updated my answer so that you can refer to print event name :)

Comment: Thanks! Just got it working I think.                                                                   
      'print(event,"is %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds away" %
      dhms_from_seconds(date_diff_in_seconds(date2, date1)))'                                                   gives me this output                                                                                                    
'What is the name of your event? Tomorrow
Enter a year 2022
Enter a month 03
Enter a day 20
Tomorrow is -1 days, 19 hours, 47 minutes, 14 seconds away'

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is likely this line:

```
date1 = datetime.date(b[1],b[2],b[3])
```

Try changing it to this:

```
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)
```